# Switch WPF Form Content

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I wanna make some game on WPF form,
And the problems I don't know how to switch between main menu form to the main game,

When I run my program, the main menu will show up, and when I click the play button
the content will be changed into the main program
but, I don't wanna make the user figure that the program change form,
so, just the form content will be changed, and the title bar stand still.

Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Is your game in the WPF application?  Can you make usercontrols that you swap in and out?

Answer (score 0):

From Xaml, you can pub both of Menu UI and Main UI in the same Grid and hide Main UI. When user clicks "Play" button on Menu, you hide Menu UI and make Main UI visible. You can add some transform or animation to make the effect smoothly.

From Code, you can use MVVM and define both Menu UI and Main UI as DataTemplate. Then you use one ContentControl with its Content bound to your Menu ViewModel. When user clicks "Play" button, you change Menu ViewModel to Main ViewModel then UI will switch automatically.